# Как добавить вставку checkbox в ячейки при генерации xlsx файла на Python?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

Мне нужно понять, как с помощью кода можно вставлять в ячейку checkbox и работать с ним. Например, при значении переменной = True, в checkbox ставится галочка. Для работы с xlsx файлами я использую библиотеку openpyxl.

Comment: Если вы и правда используете openpyxl, то вы должны знать, что и как. Вы также можете поучаствовать добавив нужный вам функционал в библиотеку.